# Do I really need to add the same element twice, one for each UIStoryboard language file?

Tags: ios, internationalization, uistoryboard

I am working in an internationalized Xcode project with two UIStoryboard files `en.lproj/Main.storyboard` and `nl.lproj/Main.storyboard`.

Is the consequence of this, that if I want to add a new element, say a UIButton to the storyboard, I have to add it twice, one for each file (and thus set the constraints etc also twice)?

This is how it looks in the navigator:

[image]

But selecting the base file actually selects the `en.lproj/Main.storyboard`, and after adding a button there it looks like I have to follow the same process in the other file.

Is this just the way it works?

Answer (score 2):

No. The usual way is that you only have **one** storyboard that contains all the UI elements, constraints etc. in your "Base" language (e.g. English). For every additional language (e.g. German) you have a strings file that contains translations for all the texts (buttons, labels etc.) in your storyboard.

[image: Xcode]

Comment: A small problem related to this is that Main.strings file won’t be updated when you add new UI components on the Storyboard. So you always have to add UI components first and then make Main.strings

Comment: Yeah. You have to update / recreate the strings files after making changes to your storyboard.

Comment: Well I am excited to know that if we'll refactor it to the way you describe, updating Main.strings is all that's needed. A third language was coming and I was afraid I'd have to maintain each storyboard file. Pfuu :-)

Comment: Yeah. A lot easier to maintain that way. :)